# OpenCL program showing errors. What can be a possible solution?

Tags: eclipse, opencl, development-environment

I am getting certain errors as shown in the image below. I think there is a problem with the setting up of environment. I am new to this and couldn't figure out how to correct it. Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5zT1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You try to `#include <CL/cl.hpp>`, which is not installed with Your OpenCL implementation, check if the `#include <CL/cl2.hpp>` is (see https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP).

If You otherwise don't make usage of the OpenCL C++ Wrapper API (see Appendix D in OpenCL 1.2), then You may want to instead `include <CL/cl.h>` or better yet (to be portable to Apple MacOS):

```c
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
```